# MIKROTIK ONE LAN - TWO WAN - TWO GATEWAY how to dispatch internet trafic depending on PC's gateway

Tags: networking, routing, mikrotik

On the LAN there are two configured type PC.

All  PC belongs to the same network (ie : 192.134.234.0/24) but there are two different gateway:

192.134.134.253 et 192.134.134.254.Each of them are connected on physical interfaces on the same

mikrotik router.

What I need is to force internet trafic from/to PC to WAN 1 or WAN 2 depending on the PC's gateway.

I don't need load balancing.

PC1 : addr: 192.134.134.1 gw: 192.134.134.253
PC2 : addr: 192.134.134.1 gw: 192.134.134.254

How to force internet trafic from/to PC1 to WAN 1 and internet trafic from/to PC2 to WAN2?

Can't find a way to achieve this although it seems a basic fonctionality.

Comment: Why do you need this? In general this is covered by policy routing, but why two different gateway addresses? Why not forward traffic based on source?